# Content property empty doesn't work in webkit?

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I have a problem with the Content property in webkit. If the value of content is empty it is not working. With all other browsers work but not with webkit ...

Look at this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/s2pf4wmg/1/

The problem is here:

```
#list li::before {
  content:""; //this is problem
  display: list-item;
}
```

This code works very well with chrome, firefox, IE ecc. In those browser before each item of ul *#list* there is only one list-style. But in safari doesn't work! in safari there are TWO list-style (two circle).

If i want to see my code work in webkit i must change this:

```
#list li::before {
  /*  content:""; */
  display: list-item;
}
```

Why this problem ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve with that code.

Comment: an ordinate list, but if you don't see jsfiddle with Webkit and after with firefox you can't understand

Comment: Maybe transition on pseudo elements don't support by webkit?

Comment: You can't transition the `content` property but I'm stil not clear on why you are using a pseduo-element with `display:list-item`.

Comment: Because if you delete "display: list-item", before each item there will not a golden circle (list-style). Try and open jsfiddle with firefox for example... Besides do you think that the only way is to do a js code when where the browser is webkit i change css and delete content: " "  ???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
{
 display: flex;
}
```

it works if add **-webkit-flex**